# Unable to decode StackTrace error

Tags: java, stack-trace, bibtex

Working with bibtex Library I am getting following error:

```
Bib Parse error [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@8814e9
Bib Parse error [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@228a02
```

I get no idea how to decode this and to find actual error

Comment: use a debugger and catch the exception

Comment: @IwishIcouldthinkofagood kindly elaborate. I am already catching exception

Comment: re-read the first 3 words that I wrote.